# Tag ranking shows different tables for logged in user

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, tags, top-users

I'm seeing different tables for the jax-ws tags when I'm logged into SO and when I'm logged out. Logged in:

[image: Logged In]

Logged out:

[image: Logged Out]

As you should be able to see, when I'm logged in, I'm second to last in the pile for 30 days. When I'm logged out, I'm fourth from the bottom. I sampled the java-ee tag for the anomaly too and it gets weirder for when I'm logged out. with 6 votes and 4 questions, I'm ranked below another user with 6 votes and 10 questions.

[image]

As a corollary to this question; When I'm logged in, it appears that for the all-time rankings in all tags, I'm tacked on to the bottom of the tables even when I have no business being there with negligible votes. Why?

Comment: Have you tried viewing the page with two different browsers (one with your account logged-in and the other as a guest), and refreshing at the same time (at least, with the least amount of time between the refreshes)?

Comment: @MarkGarcia Yes, I'm using both Chrome and firefox and it's consistent with both. The last scrnshot is from firefox. Firefox was my control, where I remained permanently logged out. I kept logging in and out on chrome. Flushed caches on both too

Comment: The last part is by-design - you're tacked on to the list so that you can see your stats. The first part I'm not sure about; I see the same thing, so it's not a matter of things appearing differently *just for you*.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the first part, the stats are shown by rank. Within the same rank, the order is unspecified, so it depends on how SQL compiles the query we use.

In particular, we use different queries for logged in users to ensure they appear in the rankings: this evidently changes enough in the way the query is compiled by SQL Server so that the order within a rank changes.

The second part was addressed by [Shog9 in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181988/tag-ranking-shows-different-tables-for-logged-in-user#comment553801_181988).